# Should an edit be accepted if a user speaks in the answerers name?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Strolling through the Review Queues I come across a suggested edit for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831430/1870795

The suggested edit is by an `anonymous user` and adds a code variation that was posted as comment by a user who did not post the original answer.

Original answer:

> How about something along the lines:
>
> com_vals = df['Home_team_scores'].unique()
>   df['full_scores_list'].apply(lamda v: v in com_vals)

The suggested edit adds:

> Improved according to comments:
>
> Instead of the lambda-function, you can use a helper function for the
>   apply():
>
> com_vals = df['Home_team_scores'].unique() def helper():   return v
>   in com_vals df['full_scores_list'].apply(helper)
>
> You can more fine-grainded controll the outputs and conditions in the helper() function. I do not quite understand the in and outputs that you have, so this is all I can currently provide. be a little more detailed with an example dataframe and expected output

The edit is based on the original answer and reads as if it was a statement  by the original answerer, e.g. `I do not quite understand...`.

Now I wonder:

- Should the edit be approved considering that the suggested edit speaks in the answerers' name by using the first person `I...`?
- Should the subjective part be re-edited into a general statement without using the first person?
- Could the anonymous user even be the original answerer?

Comment: @HansPassant My point is the phrasing of the edit. The editor writes `I do not understand` / `all I can currently provide`. These are statements about personal ability and knowledge of the answerer by a person who is not the answerer. That looks strange.

Comment: I removed those parts as they don't add anything to the answer.

Comment: FWIW, the `helper` function is only a minor cosmetic improvement, with no difference in functionality to the original code.

Answer (score 13):

That edit should not have been approved, **in my opinion**. There is no evidence that the user suggesting the edit is the author of the original answer, yet it speaks in the name of said author.

What should have been done instead is

- if the editor is in fact the author he should've edited it while being logged in
- if he's not, it should have been a separate answer, possibly CW if relying on the previous answer

Either way, again, in my opinion, not an edit worthy of approval.

Comment: Another possiblity is that the editor is copying comments made by the original author, and adding them to the answer. But that doesn't seem to be case here.

Comment: That begs the question if any answer should ever contain any reference to the author in an environment where answers have the nature of being co-authored. That includes the original answerer, because it is possible that the answer will be co-authored or even become a community answer. Personal references are not relevant to the answer anyway. On the other hand it keeps a human touch to refer to one-self.

Comment: @Manuel Given that answers often contain personal opinion (such as the very answer we're commenting on) some way to make it clear what parts are personal opinion is probably important. I don't think that this causes huge problems for co-authored or community answers if we phase out the personal references there, or turn them into group references when the group of others all agrees on something that involves personal opinion.